# Enumerating a list with multiple lines labels

Tags: lists, luatex, enumerate, enumitem

I am making a list of problems for a contest that should look like this:

```
Problem 1. Some text 
5 points   As the text continues it stays aligned
           to this
           |<--
           |<--
            Invisible line
Problem 2. More text
1 point    also aligned
```

I want to use an enumerate-like environment, like

```
\newenvironment{questions}{
\begin{list}{ 
    \bfseries\upshape\arabic{qcounter}.
}{
    \renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{%
\textbf{\refstepcounter{qcounter}\arabic{qcounter}##1.}}%
    \usecounter{qcounter}
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{2.5em}
    \setlength{\labelsep}{0.5em}
\setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep}
        \setlength{\itemsep}{2pt}
        \setlength{\listparindent}{1em}
    \setlength{\parsep}{1pt}
    \setlength{\topsep}{6pt}
} 
}{    
    \end{list}
}
```

I have changed renewing of `makelabel` to

```
\renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{%
\textbf{\refstepcounter{qcounter}Problem \arabic{qcounter}##1.}\\##1 points}
```

but it didn't work. I also tried putting it into `minipage`, but the text of the item looks strange after it.

I also want to give `item` to arguments: number of points and the ending or the word points, like `point##2`, because I write in russian and the ending of the word changes strongly, depending on the number.

Is there any option I can do such a list?

My code (LuaLaTeX):

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape]{extarticle}
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=1cm, left=0.25in, right=0.25in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{skull}
\usepackage{faktor}
\usepackage{xfrac} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
%
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}    
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}   
\setmainlanguage{russian}


\newcounter{qcounter}
\newenvironment{questions}{
\begin{list}{ 
    \bfseries\upshape\arabic{qcounter}.
}{
    \renewcommand{\makelabel}[1]{%
\textbf{\refstepcounter{qcounter}\arabic{qcounter}##1.}}%
    \usecounter{qcounter}
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{2.5em}
    \setlength{\labelsep}{0.5em}
\setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep}
        \setlength{\itemsep}{2pt}
        \setlength{\listparindent}{1em}
    \setlength{\parsep}{1pt}
    \setlength{\topsep}{6pt}
} 
}{    
    \end{list}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\item[1] \lipsum[1]

\item[2] \lipsum[2]

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It think it would be simpler to do with a theorem-like structure.

Comment: @Bernard, but what about alignment in that case?

Comment: You can use the `\theoremindent`parameter (from `ntheorem`) and use the optional argument of a theorem environment for the second line. With  a list and `enumitem` I don't see how to have an optional argument for `\item` in  a simple way.

Comment: There is also \hangindent, or \letskip and \llap{\makebox[\leftskip][l]{...}}

Answer (score 2):

```
\usepackage{calc}
\newcounter{qcounter}
% Item parameter is number of points.
% See The LaTeX Companion, Second Edition, page 150.
\newcommand{\questionlabel}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{qcounter}\raisebox{0pt}[1ex][0pt]%
  {\makebox[\labelwidth][l]%
    {\parbox[t]{\labelwidth}%
      {\hspace{0pt}\textbf{Problem \arabic{qcounter}}\\#1 points}}}}

\newenvironment{questions}
{\begin{list}{}{\let\makelabel\questionlabel
    \setlength{\itemsep}{2pt}
    \setlength{\listparindent}{1em}
    \setlength{\parsep}{1pt}
    \setlength{\topsep}{6pt}
    \settowidth{\labelwidth}{\textbf{Problem 99}}%
    \setlength{\labelsep}{0.5em}%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep}%
    \usecounter{qcounter}}
}
{    
    \end{list}
}
```